# Modifying classList using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble changing the classes for a table row.

My HTML

```
<table class="table table-light table-bordered text-center">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Ava</th>
        <th scope="col">Full name</th>
        <th scope="col">Registred</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#users}}
        <tr class="table-light" id="colorised">
            <td><img src="{{avaUrl}}" width="42" height="42"/></td>
            <td><a href="users/{{_id}}" style="margin-top: 50px;">{{username}}</a></td>
            <td>{{registeredAt}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/users}}
    </tbody>
    {{^users}}
    </br>
    <strong style="color: orange">No results for "{{searchedUsername}}"</strong>
    </br>
    </br>
    {{/users}}
</table>
```

And JavaScript

```
<script>
      $('#colorised').attr('class','table-success');
</script>
```

How can I change the colour of the table row ?

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in the DOMReady event?

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: If your using bootstrap 4.0 you should really consider using [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and not tables

Comment: How do you have non HTML tags as children of a table? When you have no children, you have invalid HTML.

Comment: Why are you not using your templating to add the class?

Comment: @Liam Not sure if it's true for all cases - In this particular example I think that it is preferred to put the data in an actual table (Unless there is a new best practice that I'm not familiar with)

Comment: {{#users}} is looping those rows right? You'll get duplicate ids that way. id is unique identifier and behavior of having duplicate ids is undefined in browsers. So weird things might start to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle between the classes to switch them over:

```
$('#colorised').toggleClass('table-light table-success');
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute your code after the DOM has finished loading so that it is ready for access or modification you need to wrap your jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`. It is assumed that your code is located before DOM elements such as in the  tag or in the top or middle of the  section before some DOM elements and that code does attempt to access the DOM upon first initialization.

So that it should be placed into a `$(document).ready()` block so it will not execute before the DOM is ready.The short hand for `$(document).ready()` is `$(function() {});` Here is an example for the code provided by you.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorised').attr('class','table-success');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-light table-bordered text-center">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Ava</th>
        <th scope="col">Full name</th>
        <th scope="col">Registred</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#users}}
        <tr class="table-light" id="colorised">
            <td><img src="{{avaUrl}}" width="42" height="42"/></td>
            <td><a href="users/{{_id}}" style="margin-top: 50px;">{{username}}</a></td>
            <td>{{registeredAt}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/users}}
    </tbody>
    {{^users}}
    </br>
    <strong style="color: orange">No results for "{{searchedUsername}}"</strong>
    </br>
    </br>
    {{/users}}
</table>
```